# Game boy Color programming in C

Tags: c

Could someone point me to a source to begin Game Boy Color programming in C (a compiler and tutorial getting me all setup)? I have only found a bunch of broken links, and a bunch of docs making sure you have the latest "Windows 95" OS hahhaa

I am looking for step by step instructions to install and develop for Game Boy Color on Windows 7, Mac OS X, or Linux Ubuntu 12.04. Which OS would you recommend for Game Boy Color development?

Comment: Google usually answers these questions.

Comment: http://www.rrsd.com/software_development/gameboy_development/index.htm

Comment: In what way did the things you find not provide what you need? Without details it's a bit hard to provide any corrective information...

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd strongly recommend learning GBZ80 asm and writing in assembly. The Gameboy's memory model is banked and it's very difficult to deal with this from C. If your C compiler handles the banking for you with some kind of far pointers, the output code will be very large and slow. If not, you have to manually keep track of which bank you've swapped in whenever you dereference a pointer or make a function call or you'll end up accessing the wrong code/object...

Comment: Could you point me to a tutorial for GBZ80 Assembly language?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus even if it's incomplete, check this out: [ASM school](http://gameboy.mongenel.com/asmschool.html). Also, I suggest you to use [RGBDS](https://github.com/bentley/rgbds/) as assembler/linker. I also recommend UNIX or UNIX-like (Linux) as OS.

Answer (score 5):

After lots and lots of broken links here is a good one:

http://www.loirak.com/gameboy/gbprog.php

You will also need a gameboy emulator. I downloaded gb98 and it works great. As for the OS, I am still not 100% sure. I will download it on Linux tomorrow.